# Function to show max occurring letter in word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to code a function that will identify the word with most repeated letters, and I broke it down so far to identify most occurring letters in the sentence, but am unsure how to now alter the return to total repeated letters per word instead of total repeated letters per sentence.

```
function letRepeat(str) {
    var letArray = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        letArray[str[i]] = (letArray[str[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
    var max = 0;
    for (i in letArray) {
        max = Math.max(max, letArray[i]);
    }
    return letArray;
}

console.log(letRepeat("Hello there Larry Gormoon!"));
```

Output:

```
[object Object] {
   : 3,
  !: 1,
  a: 1,
  e: 3,
  G: 1,
  H: 1,
  h: 1,
  l: 2,
  L: 1,
  m: 1,
  n: 1,
  o: 4,
  r: 4,
  t: 1,
  y: 1
}
```

Also, any idea why `[object Object]` leads the output?

Comment: letArray is an object, what output do you want?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: For starters `var letArray = {};` is not an array, it is an object. `var letArray = new Array();` or `var letArray = [];`  is an array.

Comment: I'm really just trying to get `{Gormoon}` or if multiple words had the same max number of repeated letters than they would also be included in the answer.

Comment: And `max` is not currently being returned because it only tells max number of repeats, but not the letter or word. I'm still trying to incorporate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want total repeated letters per word, you just need to split the sentence into words and then modify your code a little.

```js
function countWordRpt(str) {
  var countObj = {};

  // Split the string into words,
  // and count the repeated letters in each word. 
  str.split(' ').forEach(function(word) {
    countObj[word] = function countLetRpt() {
      var letCount = {};

      // Count the repeated letters in each word.
      word.split('').forEach(function(letter) {
        letCount[letter] = ++letCount[letter] || 1;
      });

      // Find out the most repeated letters. 
      // There may be several letters repeated for most times,
      // so I use an array here.
      var max = [];
      for (var i in letCount) {
        if (letCount.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          if (letCount[max[0]] < letCount[i] || max.length === 0) {
            max = [i];
          } else if (letCount[max[0]] === letCount[i]) {
            max.push(i);
          }
        }
      }

      letCount.max = {
        letters: max,
        count: letCount[max[0]]
      };

      return letCount;
    }();
  });

  // Find out the most repeated words in the sentence.
  // Almost the same logic as above. 
  // Also, the words can be more than one, so use an array.
  var max = [];
  for (word in countObj) {
    if (countObj.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
      if (max.length === 0 ||
        countObj[word].max.count > countObj[max[0]].max.count) {
        max = [word];
      } else if (countObj[word].max.count === countObj[max[0]].max.count) {
        max.push(word);
      }
    }
  }
  countObj.max = {
    words: max,
    count: countObj[max[0]].max.count
  };

  return countObj;
}

var str = 'Hello there Larry Gormoon!';
console.log(countWordRpt(str));
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "Hello": {
        "H": 1, 
        "e": 1, 
        "l": 2, 
        "o": 1, 
        "max": {
            "letters": [
                "l"
            ], 
            "count": 2
        }
    }, 
    "there": {
        "t": 1, 
        "h": 1, 
        "e": 2, 
        "r": 1, 
        "max": {
            "letters": [
                "e"
            ], 
            "count": 2
        }
    }, 
    "Larry": {
        "L": 1, 
        "a": 1, 
        "r": 2, 
        "y": 1, 
        "max": {
            "letters": [
                "r"
            ], 
            "count": 2
        }
    }, 
    "Gormoon!": {
        "G": 1, 
        "o": 3, 
        "r": 1, 
        "m": 1, 
        "n": 1, 
        "!": 1, 
        "max": {
            "letters": [
                "o"
            ], 
            "count": 3
        }
    }, 
    "max": {
        "words": [
            "Gormoon!"
        ], 
        "count": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am attempting, however it still doesn't specify the word that has the most repeats above other words.

Comment: @CharlesWatson Check out the update... log the most repeated letters of each word.

Answer (score 1):

This code will return a object containing the words as keys and their values as objects containing the occurrences of each letter. It also produces a key/value pair indicating what word out of all of them had the most occurrences. Note, with this code, if there are two words with the same high occurrences, it will choose the last one to be processed to be added as the total.

```
function letRepeat(str) {
    var totals = {};

    // split the words into an array
    // use reduce but pass in an inital object so our output
    // is also an object
    return str.split(' ').reduce(function (p, c) {
        totals[c] = 0;

        // split each word down into letters
        // if the letter is not in the "letters object" add it
        // increment the value count
        p[c] = c.split('').reduce(function (p2, c2) {
            p2[c2] = ++p2[c2] || 1;
            if (p2[c2] > 1) totals[c]++;
            return p2;
        }, {});

        // find the word with the highest letter reoccurence
        var highest = Object.keys(totals).reduce(function (a, b) {
            return totals[a] > totals[b] ? a : b;
        });
        p.highest = { word: highest, reoccurences: totals[highest] };
        return p;
    }, {});
}

letRepeat("Hello there Larry Gormoon!");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dureeosb/3/)

Output:

Gormoon is the highest here because "o" reoccurs 2 more times.

```
{
  "Hello": {
    "H": 1,
    "e": 1,
    "l": 2,
    "o": 1
  },
  "highest": {
    "word": "Gormoon!",
    "reoccurences": 2
  },
  "there": {
    "t": 1,
    "h": 1,
    "e": 2,
    "r": 1
  },
  "Larry": {
    "L": 1,
    "a": 1,
    "r": 2,
    "y": 1
  },
  "Gormoon!": {
    "G": 1,
    "o": 3,
    "r": 1,
    "m": 1,
    "n": 1,
    "!": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would break this down into two separate functions.

One that counts the characters in a word, returning an array containing the word, and the max repeats.

```
function repCount (word) {
  var orig = word,
      len = word.length,
      mem = {},
      max = 0,
      char, i;

  word = word.toLowerCase();

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char = word[i];

    mem[char] = mem[char] + 1 || 1;

    if (mem[char] > max) {
      max = mem[char];
    } 
  }

  return [orig, max];
}
```

And one that utilizes the first, and checks each word in a sentence. You'll want to decide what constitutes a *word* in your mind. For me, it's an unbroken sequence of letters, apostrophes, and hyphens. Others may split on white space characters. Both have their shortcomings.

```
function mostRepLet (str) {
  var words = str.match(/[\w'-]+/gi),
      len = words.length,
      most = ['', 0],
      chk, i;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    chk = repCount(words[i]);

    if (chk[1] > most[1]) {
      most = chk;
    }
  }


  return most[0];
}
```

All together.

```js
var phrase = 'Hello there Larry Gormoon!';


function repCount (word) {
  var len = word.length,
      mem = {},
      max = 0,
      char, i;
  
  
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char = word[i];
    
    mem[char] = mem[char] + 1 || 1;
    
    if (mem[char] > max) {
      max = mem[char];
    } 
  }
  
  return [word, max];
}


function mostRepLet (str) {
  var words = str.match(/[\w'-]+/gi),
      len = words.length,
      most = ['', 0],
      chk, i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    chk = repCount(words[i]);
    
    if (chk[1] > most[1]) {
      most = chk;
    }
  }
  
  
  return most[0];
}


alert(mostRepLet(phrase));
```

---

`return letArray` shows an `[object Object]`, because that's precisely what `letArray` is. There are no *associative arrays* in JavaScript. There are objects, which are basically just property-value pairings, and then there are [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) objects, which are a special kind of object that has numerical indexed properties, and a `length` property.

Curly braces create an object literal: `{}`

Brackets create an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) literal: `[]`

In ES6, there are [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) objects.

Comment: This is nearly perfect. However unfortunately I have to have a single function. Using your recommendation I'm going to try to nest the second function inside.